# Joining two database sets with different datatypes

Tags: join, sas

Trying to join two datasets, but the join is based on two different data types (numeric and text)

```
SELECT *
FROM D1.T1 c
INNER JOIN
D1.T2 d
on c.CNUMBER=INPUT(d.CNUMBER, 8.) ;
```

This is does not work.

I can create a new dataset (copy existing one and add a numerical column) like this:

```
CNUMBER1=CNUMBER*1;
run;
```

Then when I join using this copy, it works... but I actually want to try to figure out the way to do it with direct Oracle connection.
In Oracle I would do:

```
on to_char(c.CNUMBER)=to_char(c.CNUMBER)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data you're joining? This will make it easier to debug.

Comment: Your first query will not work because you gave the same alias `c` to both tables.

Comment: What's the question? Doesn't your `to_char()` work?

Comment: There must be something more that's missing from the question. The `input` function should work just fine. Can you verify that `c.CNUMBER` is numeric and `d.CNUMBER` is character? What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it give an error? produce unexpected results?

Comment: This looks right to me. What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a wild guess at what you actually want:

```
PROC SQL;
  CONNECT TO ORACLE (...);
  CREATE TABLE oracle_results AS
  SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO ORACLE (
  SELECT *
  FROM D1.T1 c
  INNER JOIN
  D1.T2 d
  on to_char(c.CNUMBER)=d.CNUMBER);
  DISCONNECT FROM ORACLE;
QUIT;
```

Will connect your SAS session to Oracle, perform the explicit passthrough SQL query and pass the results back to the SAS table `oracle_results`. Replace the dots with your Oracle connection credentials.